# Where do the 2 hydrogen ions in glycolysis come from?

Tags: molecular-biology, cellular-respiration

In the reaction for glycolysis, two hydrogen ions are produced as one of the end products. In all the ten steps, I am not able to figure out where exactly these two hydrogen ions are formed. Please elucidate

Glycolysis reaction:
Glucose + 2ADP+ 2NAD+ + 2Pi ----> 2Pyruvate + 2ATP + 2NADH + 2H2O + H+

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange. Write the equation of glyolysis with glucose and pyruvate in molecular form. Then count the hydrogens, and they should match. Also, it should be $\ce{2H^+}$ in the products. You may help yourself also with [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycolysis#Overview).